# Non interactive file reading

Tags: javascript, file, local

My problem is that I want to read the content of a file from the local file system without having any need for user interaction.

I have searched several sources but only found ways that required interaction like using menues or taking another form of input. Is there no way to just access a local file and read its content in javascript?

Comment: I hope not.‎‎‎‎ It would be a wild security hole.

Comment: so you would like access to all your users' private information without them knowing?

Comment: I want to read the content of a file for configuration but I see now that this doesn't work. I guess I have to take a look at creating an appropriate instance of the file event object (or whatever it is called).
I do also think it is not the job of javascript to avoid inappropriate access to files but of the application that runs the code.